# VB script to open and close excel file without excel

Tags: excel, sharepoint, vbscript

I want to open and save an excel file in sharepoint, which has no excel installed. I tried to write an vbscript but I only can find which called excel application. Please help to advise. Thank you!

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\Roambi\Test excel\Test.xlsx")

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close

objExcel.Application.Quit

WScript.Quit
```

Comment: See [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692882.aspx) article on how to read excel files from ADODB. And [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pranavwagh/archive/2006/05/18/excel-ado.aspx) you have a extense reference on articles dealing with every problem you could find.

Comment: It's not allowed to install excel in sharepoint server. I am trying to use 2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components and finding codes to "open and save excel". I don't need to do any changes in the excel file but just open and save only.

Comment: You can read and write excel files without installing excel using adodb and the jet oledb isam drivers. Linked information uses excel to show the data and the results, but code does not use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about the reason of the issue, but if you need open and modify some content - maybe [Open XML SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425) could help. However if you need to open to run some script inside that file - you'll need to have installed Excel application